# What method makes MKPinAnnotaionView to stake to the north?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, ios6

I'm rotating the MapView according to device's heading and MKPinAnnotationView always stakes to the north.
I want to change it, what method should i change?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it before..still this annotationView behave in a very weird way..at every heading change my function rotating it the right way and after that it's jumping to the north. this happening for a view heading changes and then behaving as i aspect. can't understand it